# Google Reporting API filter contains both 'and' and 'or' operators

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

so I'm trying to a convert a custom report on Google analytics to python using the google analytics API v4. In this report the filter is as follow:

```
(cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3 .. ) AND (condn OR condX ..)
```

Currently I am using the 'dimensionFilterClauses', but this only allows concatenating the filters with one operator or the other:

```
"dimensionFilterClauses": [
        {
          "operator": 'AND',
          "filters": [
            {
              "dimensionName": "ga:browser",
              "operator": "EXACT",
              "expressions": ["Chrome"]
            }
          ]
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I did some more digging and it turned out i need to use segments. But I hit another snag with them as well, as they only allow for 'OR' filter concatenation.

So far, this is what I came up with (this is the code from samples), when I use two different segments, the end result is the two segments which can be differentiated with an extra column. How do I use different filters in the same segment?

```
"segments":[
  {
    "dynamicSegment":
    {
      "name":"Safari",
      "sessionSegment":
      {
        "segmentFilters":[
        {
          "simpleSegment":
          {
            "orFiltersForSegment":[
            {
              "segmentFilterClauses":[
              {
                "dimensionFilter":
                {
                  "dimensionName":"ga:browser",
                  "expressions":["Safari"],
                  "operator":"EXACT"
                }
              }]
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "dynamicSegment":
    {
      "name":"United States",
      "sessionSegment":
      {
        "segmentFilters":[
        {
          "simpleSegment":
          {
            "orFiltersForSegment":[
            {
              "segmentFilterClauses":[
              {
                "dimensionFilter":
                {
                  "dimensionName":"ga:country",
                  "expressions":["United States"],
                  "operator":"EXACT"
                }
              }]
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. This is from the API documentation:

```
segmentFilters[]: A segment is defined by a set of segment filters which are combined together with a logical AND operation
```

All I have to do is combine the two segments into just one segment by adding the OR filters in the segmentFilters list:

```
segments = [
{
    "dynamicSegment":
    {
        "name":"Combined",
        "sessionSegment":
        {
            "segmentFilters":[
            {
                "simpleSegment":
                {
                    "orFiltersForSegment":[
                    {
                        "segmentFilterClauses":[
                        {
                            "dimensionFilter":
                            {
                                "dimensionName":"ga:browser",
                                "expressions":["whatever you need 1"],
                                "operator":"EXACT"
                            }
                        }, {    # OR 
                            "dimensionFilter":
                            {
                                "dimensionName":"ga:browser",
                                "expressions":[" or whatever you need 2"],
                                "operator":"EXACT"
                            }
                        }]
                    }, {   # AND 
                    "segmentFilters":[
                    {
                    "simpleSegment":
                    {
                        "orFiltersForSegment":[
                        {
                            "segmentFilterClauses":[
                            {
                                "dimensionFilter":
                                {
                                    "dimensionName":"ga:country",
                                    "expressions":["whatever you need as need 3"],
                                    "operator":"EXACT"
                                }, {   # OR 
                                "dimensionFilter":
                                {
                                    "dimensionName":"ga:country",
                                    "expressions":["or whatever you need as need 4"],
                                    "operator":"EXACT"
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                }]]
            }
        }]
    }
}
}]
```